# Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. JMeter Integration With Azure Pipeline

Tags: git, maven, azure-pipelines, cicd

As part of the JMeter Integration With Azure Pipeline, Apche Maven installed version is 3.9.2 while using **intelliJ Terminal** and after executing the command as **mvn clean verify** getting as below:

*[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.*

*[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.*

*[ERROR]*

*[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:*

*[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException*

*[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.gstarczewski.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter-maven-wrapper</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jmeter-maven-wrapper</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>https://web.automation.itmportal.co.uk</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
          <execution>
            <id>configuration</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>configure</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>results</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Could anyone pls suggest me how to Integrate Jmeter with Azure Pipeline without Maven please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help without seeing the full output.

Minimal working Maven [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and if you put your JMeter scripts into "src/test/jmeter" folder relative to this pom.xml file they will be executed.

If Maven fails - check the full output and if it's not too informative - enable debug logging as Maven suggests.

If JMeter fails - check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)